# Do I need to remove old adhesive if putting on the same adhesive?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, vinyl

I messed up putting in my vinyl floors today. I’m using Roberts resilient glue. I ended up scraping up what glue I could, but now a thin layer of residue remains.

If I keep using the same glue, do I still need to remove the residue with goo gone? Or can I just put a new layer of glue on.

Comment: Most adhesives work best with two clean surfaces(wood and vinyl).  The addition of a third surface(residue) might make the adhesive not bond well to the wood and might not bond to itself.  It depends on the adhesive and best to read instructions or contact the maker.